# Sockets not communicating

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying to make a simple app using node and express where I can share live data with sockets. No matter what I try I can not get the server or client to send a message to one another.

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//set location for views
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
//set location for static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));

//create route 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home.jade');
});

//Connection listener for io object
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('A user has connected');
    socket.on('test', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
})

server.listen(3000, "localhost");
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://:localhost:3000');

$(document).on('click', '#submit-message', function() {
    socket.send('test', {contents: "hello"}); //static for now
});
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in either the server or browser debug console?  The structure you have looks generally OK so there must be something going wrong that is triggering some kind of error.   You need to see what that error is - hopefully in a console as a log message or by examining the network tab from the browser to see what is going on with the connection from the web page.

Comment: `http://:localhost:3000` is an invalid URL.

Comment: I don't have any errors in the browser. I know the URL looks weird but it doesn't work if I put http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now it should work..

client:

```
var socket = io();

$(document).on('click', '#submit-message', function() {
    socket.emit('test', {contents: "hello"}); //static for now
});
```

The problem is that socket.send emits always the 'message' event, it works like socket.emit('message', {contents: "hello"}). If you socket.send in the client you have to socket.on('message', function(data) {}); in the server.

Comment: And var socket = io() ;

Comment: Your the man +1. I removed the connect(ip address) from socket = io(); and it worked